# pass value from textbox to db

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Here is the scenario. I have frmMain which has a btnDepts_Click event. On that same form I have a textbox txtCustomerActive.

On my second form frmDepartments, I have set a ScalarQueryDepartments like thus using DataGridView:

```
SELECT Customer, Dept, Name FROM Departments Where Customer = ?
```

My question is, how do I get the value from frmMain textbox to my frmDepartments form where my db is setup. I know I can do txtDeptCustomer.Text = frmMain.txtCustomerActive.Text in frmDepartments load event, but how do I capture that value to pass to db. Do I just declare a variable in frmDepartments and pass that? Any help to a new user would be very much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

On your second form, declare a public Property called ID and a constructor to receive it:

```
Public Class Form2

 Public Property Id As Decimal
    'Default constructor
    Public Sub New()   

        InitializeComponent()   

    End Sub

    'Id constructor
    Public Sub New(ByVal id As Decimal)
        InitializeComponent()
        Me.Id = id   
    End Sub

End Class
```

On your first form you instantiate the form and assign the value:

```
 'Pass the desired value to the form2 constructor
 Dim form2 as new Form2(Cdec(txtDeptCustomer.Text))
 form2.show()
```

You can also use the default constructor and assign the property later:

```
Dim form2 as new Form2()
form2.Id = Cdec(txtDeptCustomer.Text)
form2.show()
```

When your Form2 is instantiated you will have the value in it. So you can access it for example in load event:

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
   'here you use the value
  Dim SqlComm as string ="SELECT Customer, Dept, Name " & _ 
      "FROM Departments Where Customer ='" & me.Id.tostring & "'"
End Sub
```

Comment: Carlos perhaps I haven't made myself very clear or I do not understand your answer. What I am trying to do is when the button is clicked, pass the value from a textbox to frmDepartments to perofrm a query. I am using this code at the moment which catches the value I need, but how do I now query database with that value and display only those values in grid. Me.DepartmentsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.StorageDataSet3.Departments)

        Dim customer As Object = frmMain.txtCustomerActive.Text
        txtDeptCustomer.Text = CType(customer, String) Thanks